# kate (ubuntu 16.04) does not have tab plugin

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, kate

I previously used `kate` on Ubuntu 14.04 which worked quite well. After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, however, the tab plugin just disappeared. So if I have just a few source files opened it becomes hard to navigate between them.

How can the tab plugin for kate (v15.12.3) work again under Ubuntu 16.04?

---

Edit: Basically what missing is the tab control. I don't know why it's left out in the latest kate version - previously there were two tab plugins (the standard one and the multi-tab plugin which allows to configure how many lines of tab bar). Now both these plugins are not present anymore so navigating among many opened documents is a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kate in KDE 4 indeed had two tabbar plugins [as discussed here](https://kate-editor.org/2011/04/25/kates-tab-bar-plugins/).

In Kate 5, these plugins were dropped in favor of a built-in tabbar. This built-in tabbar should be enabled by default and shows the used documents in a most recently used fashion. The tabbar shows as many tabs as fit, and of additional documents are open, then it says e.g. a "+5" to indicate there are 5 more documents that do not fit into the tabbar. You can reach these documents through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (if the tab switcher plugin is enabled), or through quick open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

If it's not visible, please try `Settings` > `Show Tabs`.

More information on Kate5's tabbar is available [here](https://kate-editor.org/2014/09/13/kate-and-ktexteditor-5-after-akademy-2014/) and [here (movable tabs)](https://kate-editor.org/2016/06/15/kates-tabbar-gets-movable-tabs/).

Comment: Cool thanks. I'll try and get back to you later today.

Comment: I confirm this (Ctrl + Tab) works to quickly switch between multiple tabs. Btw, the "movable tabs" you mentioned, does the standard 'kate' app (on Ubuntu 16.04) support that, or does it require something else?

Comment: As the last linked blog mentions, it was added for the KDE Applications 16.08 release - so no, it's not in Ubuntu 16.04, except if you get updates.